# Дата + 25 часов

Tags: php, дата

Всем привет, скажите вот у меня есть

```
timer()
```

Так вот мне надо сделать так чтобы к числу(time()) прибавилось 25 часов... Как прибавить 24 я понял, а вот 25 не знаю...И скажите будет ли это верным решением?

```
$datenext = time() + 1 * 25 * 3600;
```

Comment: Просто time() + 25 * 3600;

Comment: А зачем умножать на 1? Вы же и так перемножаете числа. Если time() умножить, понятно :)

Answer (score 6):

1*25 = 25

Так-что пишите проще

```
$datenext = time() + 25*3600
```

И да, это будет верно

Comment: Благодарю :)